# Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project

Tags: eclipse-plugin

While maven installation, Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'com.oracle.oats'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution in many ways.

1. This is proxy error. you check access in proxy URL (host) in IE. (Open IE ->TOOL ->INTERNET OPTIONS -> CONNECTIONS -> LAN CONNECTION.)

If it is ok this is working fine.

2. Otherwise you remove maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6. Re-execute.
3. You change eclipse-version.

If any other alternate solution. kindly update